# How to pass a Set (or network) as an argument into Python from command line

Tags: c#, python, ipc

I can't use IronPython till it has been approved and have been informed that this could take quite some time so I'm attempting to get some networking algorithms working from command line so that they can be used in C# code. I'm trying to pass a network as an argument from command line. The problem I am having is that, when I define the graph

```
 graph = {'s': {'a': 2, 'b': 1}, 'a': {'s': 3, 'b': 4, 'c':8}, 'b': {'s': 4, 'a': 2, 'd': 2}, 'c': {'a': 2, 'd': 7, 't': 4}, 'd': {'b': 1, 'c': 11, 't': 5}, 't': {'c': 3, 'd': 5}}
```

within the Python code, it works great and I get the answer I want. When I try to send it in as an argument:

```
C:\\Python27\\Python.exe C:\\PythonFiles\\DijkstraAlgorithm3.py  "{'s': {'a': 2, 'b': 1}, 'a': {'s': 3, 'b': 4, 'c':8}, 'b': {'s': 4, 'a': 2, 'd': 2}, 'c': {'a': 2, 'd': 7, 't': 4}, 'd': {'b': 1, 'c': 11, 't': 5}, 't': {'c': 3, 'd': 5}}"
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\PythonFiles\\DijkstraAlgorithm3.py", line 60, in <module>
dijkstra(args.g,'s','t')
File "C:\\PythonFiles\\DijkstraAlgorithm3.py", line 27, in dijkstra
for neighbor in graph[src] :
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

I've also noticed that the order of the network seems to be different when defined in the code versus sent in via command line though I am passing it in the same way. Here is the whole code:

```
import argparse

def dijkstra(graph,src,dest,visited=[],distances={},predecessors={}):
    # a few sanity checks
    if src not in graph:
        raise TypeError('The root of the shortest path tree cannot be found')
    if dest not in graph:
        raise TypeError('The target of the shortest path cannot be found')    
    # ending condition
    if src == dest:
        # We build the shortest path and display it
        path=[]
        pred=dest
        while pred != None:
        path.append(pred)
            pred=predecessors.get(pred,None)
        print('shortest path: '+str(path)+" cost="+str(distances[dest])) 
    else :     
        # if it is the initial  run, initializes the cost
        if not visited: 
            distances[src]=0
        # visit the neighbors
        for neighbor in graph[src] :
            if neighbor not in visited:
                new_distance = distances[src] + graph[src][neighbor]
                if new_distance < distances.get(neighbor,float('inf')):
                    distances[neighbor] = new_distance
                    predecessors[neighbor] = src
        # mark as visited
        visited.append(src)
        # now that all neighbors have been visited:    
    recurse                         
        # select the non visited node with lowest distance 'x'
        # run Dijskstra with src='x'
        unvisited={}
        for k in graph:
            if k not in visited:
                unvisited[k] = distances.get(k,float('inf'))        
        x=min(unvisited, key=unvisited.get)
        dijkstra(graph,x,dest,visited,distances,predecessors)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('g', help='This is the network')
    # Parse the given arguments
    args = parser.parse_args()
    graph = {'s': {'a': 2, 'b': 1}, 'a': {'s': 3, 'b': 4, 'c':8}, 'b': {'s': 4, 'a': 2, 'd': 2}, 'c': {'a': 2, 'd': 7, 't': 4}, 'd': {'b': 1, 'c': 11, 't': 5}, 't': {'c': 3, 'd': 5}}
    #print args.g
    #print graph
    dijkstra(args.g,'s','t')
```

Comment: Your argument `args.g` is a string but you're acting as though it's a dictionary. If you want to parse it into a dictionary, you can do that with `ast.literal_eval` as long as it's a legal Python dictionary literal.

Comment: Please don't do that. Use a configuration(JSON?) file and pass that instead ? :)

Comment: Thank you Kindall. That worked great! I cannot pass in a file unfortunately.